# Steaming large files into the S3 bucket using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

I have to download files from an external source and upload them into the S3 bucket, what i figured out so far works with small files but seemingly fails to upload for files that are a bit larger.

I get no error logs the file just remains at a really small chunk for example being 39.5 KBs instead of 49 MBs

This is the code I'm using

```
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024 * 25, max_concurrency=10,
                        multipart_chunksize=1024 * 25, use_threads=True)
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    s3.meta.client.upload_fileobj(r.raw, 'bucket_name', 'key_name', Config=config)
```

Also tried a variant with `data = BytesIO(r.content)` and then passing that instead of `r.raw`, tried playing around with `smart_open` python library but I either didn't use it well or it just didn't work for my purpose, any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Is the final size of the object in S3 the same as the length of the final streamed raw data buffer that you called `upload_fileobj` on? I presume you're simply overwriting the same object repeatedly with each subsequent streamed chunk of data, so the result is basically the final chunk, not the entire stream.

Comment: Yea, now that i think about it that's quite likely

Answer (score 0):

S3 allows you to split such files into smaller components. You upload each component in turn and then S3 combines them into the final object. You can makes use of the `FileChunkIO` module, so `pip install FileChunkIO` if it isn’t already installed.

For more go [here](https://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/s3_tut.html#storing-large-data).

Comment: That's called *multipart upload*. It has a requirement of 5MB minimum part size. It's not, in and of itself, the solution to streaming uploads. Also, your answer references the boto package, but all new code should use boto3 (as of 2015).

Comment: Any idea on how it could be done? I tried figuring something out with boto3 mutlipart upload and `response.iter_content` but I fail to make it work

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete working example of a file upload script using the boto3 library for AWS S3 interactions, along with the filechunkio and tqdm libraries for efficient handling and optional progress bar display.

```
from io import BytesIO
import os
import boto3
from filechunkio import FileChunkIO
from tqdm import tqdm  # Import tqdm for progress bar

# Chunk size for uploading in parts
chunk_size_bytes = 1024 * 1024 * 10 

# AWS S3 configuration
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='your_access_key',
    aws_secret_access_key='your_secret_key'
)
objects = session.client(service_name="s3", endpoint_url="https://your-s3-endpoint.com/", use_ssl=True)


# Local file path
source_path   = '/path/to/video.mp4'  # Full path to the local file
# Extracting the filename from the path
key_file      = os.path.basename(source_path)  # Extracted filename
# Target S3 bucket
target_bucket = "videos"  # Name of the Amazon S3 bucket
# Content type of the file
content_type  = "video/mp4"  # MIME type or content type of the file




# Create a multipart upload
response = objects.create_multipart_upload(
    ACL="public-read",
    Bucket=target_bucket,
    ContentType=content_type,
    Key=key_file
)
UploadId = response['UploadId']

# Initialize part number and parts list
part_number = 1
parts = []

try:
    # Get the total file size for tqdm
    total_size = os.path.getsize(source_path)
    # Open the local file using FileChunkIO for efficient handling of large files
    with FileChunkIO(source_path, 'rb', offset=0, closefd=True) as fd:
        for data in tqdm(iter(lambda: fd.read(chunk_size_bytes), b""), total=total_size/chunk_size_bytes, unit="MB", unit_scale=True, leave=False, dynamic_ncols=True):
            # Upload each part
            part = objects.upload_part(
                Bucket=target_bucket,
                Key=key_file,
                Body=BytesIO(data),
                PartNumber=part_number,
                UploadId=UploadId
            )
            parts.append({"PartNumber": part_number, "ETag": part["ETag"]})
            part_number += 1

    # Complete the multipart upload
    objects.complete_multipart_upload(
        Bucket=target_bucket,
        Key=key_file,
        UploadId=UploadId,
        MultipartUpload={"Parts": parts}
    )

except Exception as e:
    # Handle any exceptions, such as cleanup or logging
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    # Optionally abort the multipart upload if an error occurs
    objects.abort_multipart_upload(Bucket=target_bucket, Key=key_file, UploadId=UploadId)
    raise  # Re-raise the exception after cleanup
```